# FB.login url serves a blank page when there is no facebook cookie set on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

Something starange is happening when trying to login to facebook with the javascript SDK on mobile Safari and Android browser. When I clear both my 'history' and my 'cookies and data' and try to login to Facebook using the FB.login method, Safari and Android browser open a new tab with the auth url but stays blank. In all the desktop browsers, everything works just fine.

The strange thing is, is that when I clear my 'history' and my 'cookies and data', then visit facebook.com (not logging in or anything), close the site, open my site and then try to login to FB, it actually works like it should!

So this seems like facebook.com sets a cookie which causes the authentication URL to succesfully load.

I have looked all over for a solution for this problem but couldn't find anything and thus my first stackoverflow post...

Just to be complete, this is the code I use to init the FB SDK:

```
window.isFacebookSDKLoaded = false;
window.onFacebookSDKLoaded = function () {}; //is injected with a function from another js app on the site

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '{{ appID }}', // App ID
        channelUrl : '{{ baseUrl }}channel.php', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
    window.isFacebookSDKLoaded = true;
    window.onFacebookSDKLoaded();
};

(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
```

Someplace else in my app I just simply do:
(using google closure)

```
mm.controller.facebook.DoFBLogin.prototype.doLogin = function ()
{
    FB.login( goog.bind( this.loginResult, this ), { scope: app.Config.getFBPermissions() } );
}

mm.controller.facebook.DoFBLogin.prototype.loginResult = function ( result )
{
    // logged in
};
```

If someone has a solution... Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem with the blank screen. just tried to reproduce your conditions by logging in to facebook.com but I still get the blank screen.